# ArgoCD can't pull image despite providing dockerconfigjson

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm currently trying to add ArgoCD to my project and am struggling with pulling an image from my GitLab container registry.

Here's my values yaml:

```yaml
# Default values for oc-backend.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: registry.gitlab.com/open-concepts/open-concepts-backend
  tag: master
  pullPolicy: Always

imagePullSecrets:
  - name: registry-credentials
nameOverride: "oc-app"
fullnameOverride: "oc-backend-test"

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: true
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: ""

podSecurityContext:
  {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext:
  {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 80

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations:
    {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: []

  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

resources:
  {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

And the secret yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registry-credentials
  namespace: argocd
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: xxxx
```

I know for a fact that the dockerconfigjson works because I've tested it beforehand.

```
➜ kubectl get secret registry-credentials --namespace=argocd
NAME                   TYPE                             DATA   AGE
registry-credentials   kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson   1      56m
```

Yet, I'm still getting denied errors via ArgoCD. Can someone check whether my configuration is correct?

TIA

Comment: ArgoCD doesn't pull images. Your kubernetes cluster does that (when it creates a Pod). You said, "I know for a fact that the dockerconfigjson works because I've tested it beforehand"; can you show us how you've tested it? Can you successfully deploy a Pod into manually (without argocd) into your cluster? What are the specific errors you're seeing w/r/t pulling images?

Comment: You are right. I'd made changes to the secret and had forgotten. I'll close the question

Answer (score 2):

Solution: I'd removed the user, password and email before encoding it. It's now working!

Comment: could you be more specific here? I would think the password is needed for private container repos on GitLab…

Maybe you could share the obfuscated text or the command you used to create it?